# Understanding the Impact of Including ConstraintLayout Dependency in Android Projects

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm using constraintlayout to design my activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">
...
```

Acording documentation I need to include `implementation` line in `dependencies` section in `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
```

But I don't see any difference in having or not having implementation line in my `build.gradle` file. Project runs fine in both cases. Why?

P.S.
I do `Sync now` in both cases

Comment: maybe it is already included by other dependencies... please check the dependencies list

Comment: How to check is dependency includes required dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Android adopted androidx, developers had to include the constraintlayout library separately, but now, constraintlayout is integrated within androidx, eliminating the need for additional library imports.